# Partialy colored output

Tags: c, colors

I have a program that prints out 2 columns. I want only the left one to have color and the color can be chosen with a cmd argument. I know how to do it, but I want to ask if this is really the only way to do it:

```c
void color(char *c)
{
    if (c == "b")
        printf("\x1b[34m");
    if (c == "r")
        printf("\x1b[31m");
    /* More colors ... */
}

void colres(void)
{
    printf("\x1b[0m");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    char *c = "r";
    /* Possible arguments are 'b' and 'r' */
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "c:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'c': c = optarg; break;
        }
    }

    /* Calls to other functions */
    char *valueFromFunction = "string";

    color(c);    
    printf("col1");
    colres();
    printf("\t%s\n", valueFromFunction);
    /* More printing and color (re)setting */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look to the Colors section of ncurses: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html

Comment: I think the methods of setting color will depend on your terminal and aren't really c-specific (although you could use ncurses as suggested above). But if your concern is about all the calls to start/restore the color, I would suggest creating a function that takes a color and the text and prints it in that color. e.g. `void printfcolor(char *color, char *text)`

Comment: @DavidRanieri I'm really trying to avoid ncurses, the program is relatively small and I only need the colors, so ansi escape sequences should do the trick just fine

Comment: @EdmCoff I didn't think about that. That should hopefully do the trick thanks!